Swift Generic vs Non-Generic Function Call Precedence
Here is my code:
import Foundation
import Combine

func todo() -> Never{ fatalError("Not Implemented!") }

protocol WASMDecodable{
    init(from decoder: WASMDecoder) throws
}

protocol WASMLeafDecodable: WASMDecodable{}
extension WASMLeafDecodable{
    init(from decoder: any WASMDecoder) throws { self = try decoder.decode(Self.self) }
}

protocol WASMTopLevelDecoder{
    associatedtype Input
    func decode<T: WASMDecodable>(_ type: T.Type, from input: Self.Input) throws -> T
}

protocol WASMDecoder{
    func decode<T: WASMDecodable>(_ type: T.Type) throws -> T
    func decode(_ type: UInt8.Type) throws -> UInt8
}

extension WASMDecoder{
    
}

class WASMBinaryContainer: WASMDecoder{
    
    func decode(_ type: UInt8.Type) throws -> UInt8 {
        todo()
    }
    
    func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type) throws -> T where T : WASMDecodable {
        try T(from: self)
    }
    
}

class WASMBinaryDecoder: WASMTopLevelDecoder{
    func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type = T.self, from input: Data) throws -> T where T : WASMDecodable {
        try WASMBinaryContainer(bytes: input).decode(type)
    }
}

extension UInt8: WASMLeafDecodable{ }

let a: UInt8 = try WASMBinaryDecoder().decode(from: Data([0x01, 0x02]))


The compiler always chose to call the func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type) throws -> T where T : WASMDecodable instead of non-generic one.
Is there a way to let it choose to call the non-generic one.
I try to modify the non-generic one to this:
func decode<T: WASMDecodable>(_ type: T.Type) throws -> T where T == UInt8
But it will only spit out a warning that says this will be an error in swift 6, and will not affect the compiler's choice.

This is not about "precedence". Overloads are resolved at compile time, not at runtime, so .decode(type) can only resolve to the generic overload, because the compile-time type of type is T.Type. Similarly for .decode(Self.self), the compiler doesn't know which concrete type Self is.
The idea of WASMLeafDecodable having a default implementation like that simply doesn't work. This would cause infinite recursion.
UInt8 should just implement WASMDecodable like this:
extension UInt8: WASMDecodable {
    init(from decoder: any WASMDecoder) throws {
        // here the compiler obviously knows the concrete type of UInt8.self, 
        // and can resolve the call to the non-generic overload
        self = try decoder.decode(UInt8.self)
    }
}

This is basically how the built-in Codable works too. See its source and you will find the primitive types (or in your words, "leaves") all explicitly implementing Codable. There is no such thing as a LeafDecodable.
// https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Codable.swift#L5098
extension Double: Codable {
  public init(from decoder: any Decoder) throws {
    self = try decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(Double.self)
  }

  public func encode(to encoder: any Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
    try container.encode(self)
  }
}

In fact, I'd recommend reusing the built-in Codable protocols, instead of creating your own WASMDecodable. You don't need to support everything. Just throw an error for the things you don't support. See CodableCSV for an example.

Thanks for answering. Actually I've considered reusing Codable protocol, but I need it to support decoding for struct. For Codable protocol, the struct decodes with a keyed container, which is not supported under this situation, and I really want to find a way to avoid manually write the decoding function for each struct.

@赵家辉 if that’s your goal, creating your own protocols will not help either. Consider using a macro to generate the conformance that doesn’t use keyed containers.

ok I'll consider using a swift macro then
